# Выводит удаленные записи из БД

Tags: c#, nhibernate

вот моя настройка nhibernate где я говорю, что не выводить записи у которых "IsDeleted = true" в БД :

```
public abstract class NHSessionProviderBase {
    private ISessionFactory _factory;
    private readonly object SyncObject = new object();
    private readonly Assembly _entitiesAssembly;
    private readonly bool _schemaUpdate;
    private readonly FilterDefinition SoftDeleteDefinition;

    public string ConnectionString { get; }

    public NHSessionProviderBase(string connectionString, Assembly entitiesAssembly, bool schemaUpdate = false) {
        SoftDeleteDefinition = new FilterDefinition(
            "softdelete",
            string.Format("(IsDeleted = :{0})", "isDeleted"),
            new Dictionary<string, IType> { { "isDeleted", NHibernateUtil.Boolean } }, true);
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        _entitiesAssembly = entitiesAssembly;
        _schemaUpdate = schemaUpdate;
    }
    public ISession OpenSession() {
        var session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        ApplyFilters(session);
        return session;
    }
    public IStatelessSession OpenStatelessSession() {
        return GetSessionFactory().OpenStatelessSession();
    }
    private void ApplyFilters(ISession session) {
        var type = SoftDeleteDefinition.ParameterTypes.First().Value as PrimitiveType;
        session
            .EnableFilter(SoftDeleteDefinition.FilterName)
            .SetParameter(SoftDeleteDefinition.ParameterNames.First(), type.DefaultValue);
    }

    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory() {
        if (_factory == null) {
            lock (SyncObject) {
                if (_factory == null) {
                    var configuration = PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                        .IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                    var mapping = AutoMap.Assembly(_entitiesAssembly)
                                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBaseEntity)))
                                .UseOverridesFromAssembly(_entitiesAssembly)
                                .Conventions.AddAssembly(_entitiesAssembly)
                                .Conventions.Add<EnumConvention>()
                                .Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>()
                                .Conventions.Add<BinaryColumnLengthConvention>()
                                .Conventions.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
                    AddIgnoredBase(mapping);
                    AddConventions(mapping.Conventions);
                    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(configuration//.ShowSql()
                                .UseReflectionOptimizer())
                        .Mappings(c => c.AutoMappings.Add(mapping))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetListener(ListenerType.Delete, new SoftDeleteEventListener()))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.AddFilterDefinition(SoftDeleteDefinition));
                    if (_schemaUpdate) {
                        cfg.ExposeConfiguration(x => new SchemaUpdate(x).Execute(false, true));
                    }
                    var build = cfg.BuildConfiguration();
                    foreach (var classMap in build.ClassMappings) {
                        if (typeof(IDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(classMap.MappedClass)) {
                            classMap.AddFilter(SoftDeleteDefinition.FilterName, SoftDeleteDefinition.DefaultFilterCondition);                                
                        }
                    }
                    _factory = build.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
            }
        }
        return _factory;
    }

    private void AddIgnoredBase(AutoPersistenceModel mapping) {
        foreach (var ignored in this.IgnoredBaseClasses()) {
            mapping.IncludeBase(ignored);
        }
    }
    private void AddConventions(SetupConventionFinder<AutoPersistenceModel> conventions) {
        foreach (var convention in this.CustomConventions()) {
            conventions.Add(convention);
        }
    }
    protected virtual Type[] CustomConventions() { return new Type[0]; }
    protected virtual Type[] IgnoredBaseClasses() { return new Type[0]; }
}
```

Тут работает:

```
var query = _session.Query<Store>(x => x.Organization.Xin == xin).Select(x => new {
                x.Name,                
                x.IsDeleted
            });
```

Но когда делаешь SelectMany, оно выводит удаленные записи:

```
var q = _session.Query<Organization>(x => x.Xin == xin).SelectMany(x => x.Stores).Select(x => new {
                x.IsDeleted,
                x.Name
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

может кому-то поможет :

```
public class OrganizationOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Organization> {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Organization> mapping) {
            mapping.HasMany(x => x.Stores).ApplyFilter<SoftDeleteDefinition>();
        }
    }
```

и сам фильтр:

```
public class SoftDeleteDefinition : FilterDefinition {
        public SoftDeleteDefinition() {
            this.WithName("mappingSoftDelete");
            this.WithCondition(string.Format("(IsDeleted = :{0})", "isDeleted"));
            this.AddParameter("isDeleted", NHibernateUtil.Boolean);
        }
    }
```